usage of は in this passage (instead of を)
The following is a excerpt from a podcast. The speaker has been sick and hasn't been releasing podcasts as often as usual. I would like to focus on the three occurences of は I put in bold:
一応体調は落ち着いてきたので、来週もまた一週間に一回ぐらいのペースに戻したいと思いますがちょっとね、仕事が忙しいからね、もしかしたらまた少し遅れることはあるかもしれませんがポッドキャストを辞めたりはしないのでそこは安心してください。あと、メッセージとかメールを送ってくれた人の返事もね、遅くなりますけど、かならず一人一人のメッセージは全部読んでそして時間が出来た時にゆっくり返事はして行きますので、時間がかかって申し訳ないですけど、返事は少し待っててくださいね。
In all three cases, it's not clear to me why the direct object marker を isn't used instead of は. None of the functions of は I am familiar with seem to fit in this context. What do you think of this usage?

Explaining nuances is difficult, because some rhetorical effects often occur indirectly from the grammar.
In this case, let's start from the fact that は sets a topic for the context thereafter, and every Japanese statement needs a topic. If you said:

かならず一人一人のメッセージを全部読んで（……）返事をして行きます（……）返事を少し待っててくださいね

words before respective を cannot be the topic, so other things must be filled in as topics. As usual, simple declarative without any qualified topic in context is talking about me (speaker) by default, and imperative about you (same with subject in these cases). So this would be a plain sentences like:

I'd definitely read messages from every one of you, [...] I make replies one by one, [...] please wait for replies a little longer.

In contrast,

かならず一人一人のメッセージは全部読んで（……）返事はして行きます（……）返事は少し待っててくださいね

is resetting the topic to the preceding word, which would be effectively like:

messages from every one of you: to be definitely read by me; [...] replies: to be made one by one by me; [...] replies: please wait for them a little longer.

You can say it is focusing or emphasizing, which is technically a bit inaccurate. The speaker is bringing back those words (メッセージ, 返信) as the starting point for coming statements again and again, and this is reminding the hearer what they are talking about every time, which practically makes it one of devices allowed in Japanese to ensure the hearer what the speaker cares about: in this context, correspondences with their listeners.
It is indeed a colloquial feature, not in the sense that being grammatically nonstandard, but that in speech you need to repeatedly capture short-term attention of the audience to make your point across, which is less needed in written language.
